# How to present data with binding and DataTemplate -or- ContentControl for MAUI

Tags: controltemplate, maui

**How to present a string, number or a also view model with binding and DataTemplate?**

I am looking for a MAUI replacement for the WPF ContentControl.

The `ContentView` has a Content property but this is from type `View`.
The `ContentPresenter` has a Content property but this is also from type `View`. *<Ignorable>WTF, Why this is not named ViewPresenter when it can only present a View??? Someoteimes MAUI is weird.</Ignorable>*

How to present any content with defining DataTemplates for each data type?

```
class PropertyViewModel {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public object Value {get;set;}
}
```

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="System.String">
        <Entry Text="{Binding}/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="System.Int32">
        <NumberPicker Value="{Binding}/>
    </DataTemplate>
    .. more templates, eg. DatePicker for System.DateOnly
</Page.Resources>

<DockLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding Name}
    <TemplatedContenView Content={Binding Value}/> 
</DockPanel>
```

The TemplatedContenView or ContentControl (that does not exist in MAUI), can use **different** templates for **different** types of Value. In WPF the ContentControl uses ContentTemplate, ContentTemplateSelector or if none specified it looked into the resources to find the template.

*<Ignorable>I often have the feeling with MAUI that I have to constantly reinvent things that are standard in WPF. Yes I know MAUI is not WPF, but there should still be at least similar concepts. The switch from WinForms to WPF was much easier and the differences were considerably greater.</Ignorable>*

**Edit1:** a more detailed example

Answer (score 9):

I'm a WPF developer and recently I've started MAUI project. And It looks like you have to reinvent the wheel every time when you are going to write such a simple scenario as you mentioned :(. When you do it using WPF you even don't need to thought about that, it's too easy to implement, but when you use MAUI you should break your mind to do such minor things.

I also encountered the same issue and I didn't find a simple in-box solution. But I came up with the idea to create a control with some layout inside that has attached properties from BindableLayout

**TemplatedContentPresenter.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class TemplatedContentPresenter : ContentView
{
    public TemplatedContentPresenter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty DataTemplateSelectorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DataTemplateSelector), typeof(DataTemplateSelector), typeof(TemplatedContentPresenter), null, propertyChanged: DataTemplateSelectorChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty DataTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DataTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(TemplatedContentPresenter), null, propertyChanged: DataTemplateChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty DataProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Data), typeof(object), typeof(TemplatedContentPresenter), null, propertyChanged: DataChanged);

    public DataTemplateSelector DataTemplateSelector
    {
        get =>(DataTemplateSelector)GetValue(DataTemplateSelectorProperty);
        set => SetValue(DataTemplateSelectorProperty, value);
    }

    public DataTemplate DataTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(DataTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(DataTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get => GetValue(DataProperty);
        set => SetValue(DataProperty, value);
    }

    private static void DataTemplateSelectorChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if(bindable is TemplatedContentPresenter contentPresenter && newValue is DataTemplateSelector dataTemplateSelector)
        {
            BindableLayout.SetItemTemplateSelector(contentPresenter.HostGrid, dataTemplateSelector);
        }
    }
    private static void DataTemplateChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (bindable is TemplatedContentPresenter contentPresenter && newValue is DataTemplate dataTemplate)
        {
            BindableLayout.SetItemTemplate(contentPresenter.HostGrid, dataTemplate);
        }
    }

    private static void DataChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (bindable is TemplatedContentPresenter contentPresenter)
        {
            BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(contentPresenter.HostGrid, new object[] { newValue });
        }
    }
}
```

**TemplatedContentPresenter.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.TemplatedContentPresenter">
    <Grid x:Name="HostGrid" x:FieldModifier="private" />
</ContentView>
```

**Usage:**

```
<Frame WidthRequest="500" HeightRequest="500">
     <controls:TemplatedContentPresenter 
               Data="{Binding}" 
               DataTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CardTemplateSelector}"/>
</Frame>
```

**UPD:**
While I was writing the answer I came up with another solution with a simple converter:
**SingleObjectToArray.xaml**

```
    internal class SingleObjectToArray : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new object[] { value };
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
<Frame>
    <Frame.Resources>
        <converters:SingleObjectToArray x:Key="SingleObjectToArrayConverter"/>
    </Frame.Resources>
    <Grid BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SingleObjectToArrayConverter}}"
          BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CardTemplateSelector}" /> 
</Frame>
```

Comment: I was afraid it would come to this. Your answer is well structured and it answers OP very well. However this will lead to people abusing this control and making it something it shouldn't be. I am starting with MAUI and am investigating this exact scenario. Since using `ContentView` throws exception and specifying Pages in code behind eliminates all WPF fun we had. This is maybe because of mobile development but on desktop, that's a step back.

Comment: Why didn't you just use a `CollectionView` for your second approach?

Comment: This is great. One thing I still miss from WPF is that you could declare a static DataTemplate for a given type, and then any type of presentation for that data would default to using that data-template. You didn't have to use a selector. Done anything in this direction? I would assume you have to have some sort of global DataTemplateSelector that would load up DataTemplates from the App resource dictionary(s) and index them by data type.

Comment: Honestly, between your approaches, I prefer the first one because it allows me to put all logic in a single class and use it wherever I need. Even the second one is very clever, but I think is less straightforward... However, this answer totally deserve and upvote! GG!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DXContentPresenter](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/403983/utility-controls/index?v=23.2#content-presenter) from the free [DevExpress suite](https://www.devexpress.com/maui/) to reuse DataTemplates:

```xml
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="employeeTemplate">
            <!-- ... -->
            <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    <dx:DXContentPresenter Content="{Binding Employee}"
                           ContentTemplate="{StaticResource employeeTemplate}" />
```

Please note that DevExpress offers only mobile components (iOS, Android)

Answer (score 0):

Circumventing `ItemTemplateSelector` as suggested by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8102482/alex-russkov) is clever, but introduces some delays perceptible to end user (a few ms). This is particularly visible when done in `CollectionView`.

One way to acheive conditional template binding is to use [ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-8.0).

This way you can:

1. Create a `ControlTemplate` for each of your use case in a `ResourceDictionary`.
2. In your view model add a `ControlTemplate` property that fetch the correct `ControlTemplate` from your resource according to your business logic.
3. In your xaml consume your template asis `<ContentView ControlTemplate="{Binding ViewModel.Template}"/>`